# Writing a Spark SQL view with several WrappedArray columns to CSV fails

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to write a view in Spark SQL to a CSV file, but it's failing because I have several columns of type WrappedArray in the view. The error message I'm getting is

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support array data type.

The code used to write the file (modified to avoid revealing the nature of the data) in a %spark shell on Zeppelin 2.7 is

```
spark.table("my_view").repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv("hdfs://path/to/my_output.csv")
```

I'm presuming I need to convert the WrappedArray to a list of strings before writing to csv. A snippet of one column of this view looks something like

```
WrappedArray(992, 704, 721, 705), null, WrappedArray(105)
```

I would like these to be converted to

```
"992, 704, 721, 705", "", "105"
```

respectively before writing to csv - suppressing the spaces in the result strings would be OK. My Spark/Scala skills are pretty limited, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the output of `spark.table("my_view").show(false)` and `spark.table("my_view").printSchema` ?

Comment: Look at the spark function explode, that should give you what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a select statement in Spark SQL using the idiom `concat_ws(",", varname) as varname` for each of the 20 or so instances where I had an array of strings, where an individual string was a WrappedArray.

To answer Ramesh's question, the variables in question were of type array(string), where an individual element of the array is a WrappedArray. Therefore, a simulation of the actual call that finally worked was as follows. Code is in a Zeppelin 2.7.x notebook.

```
%spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions concat_ws
val my_data spark.read.parquet(<path_to_file>).createOrReplaceTempView("dat")

%sql
create or replace temp view dat2 as
select var1, var2, concat_ws(",", var3) as var3, var4 from dat
where <stuff happens>
```

The effect of `concat_ws()` is to convert an array of strings to a string object.

Thanks to all who responded - I learned a few things that will come in handy in the future.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting of code. The %spark or %sql is the first line of a Zeppelin shell, denoting which engine should be used. In the first line of code, the import reads in the concat_ws() function, after which 'val' starts the next line of code in the cell. In the %sql cell, I meant to put in 'where [stuff happens]'. As you can tell, I'm rather new to this - I'll read the formatting of posts more carefully in the future.

Comment: Could you edit your post with the correct formatting? It's not particularly readable at the moment.